# trying to compile my sass with css in json "npm run sass"

Tags: css, json, sass, npm-run

i have install sass i am trying to compile my sass with css in json. In the script part I think I correctly linked the sass and css files. But when I run "npm run sass" I have this problem.
Why do you think?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw9Vn.png)

Comment: Hello! Provide full package.json as text, please. As far as I see, you have excess or missing char inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i would like to say that Ruby sass is in end of life and you should look for node-sass.

You have some typo you miss the = after the --style.
AND for one file you don't need : between input and output.

So that give this :

```
npm run sass --watch ./code/style.sass ./code/style.css --style=extended
```